# How to find out Cocoapods library dependencies?

Tags: xcode7, cocoapods

When I run pod install, I am seeing libraries installed that are not specified in Podfile.  Presumably these are the dependencies of the libraries specified.  How do I go about finding out which library in Podfile causes a specific library to be installed?

For example, PureLayout is not specified in my Podfile, I would like to know what's in my Podfile that causes this to be installed.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.6.3)
Installing Bolts (1.6.0)
Installing CocoaLumberjack (2.2.0)
Installing PureLayout (3.0.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you open the `Podfile.lock` file, you can see the dependencies of a pod in the `PODS` section:

```
PODS:
  - KIF (3.3.0):
    - KIF/Core (= 3.3.0)
  - KIF/Core (3.3.0)
  - OCHamcrest (4.3.0)
  - OCMockito (2.0.1):
    - OCHamcrest (~> 4.0)
```

This shows that KIF is requiring KIF/Core (a ["subspec"](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec) in the Cocoapods parlance), and OCMockito is requiring OCHamcrest (a dependency on a completely separate Cocoapod).